# Avoid writing to file after each update in DeltaTable

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I am performing transformations on a Delta table using PySpark and the [DeltaTable library](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#conditional-update-without-overwrite). The code:

```
from delta import *

delta_tb = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, 'path/to/table')
delta_tb.update(set = {'ma': 'round(ma, 5)'})
```

to round the `ma` column to 5 decimal places. The update acts directly on the file at `path/to/table`, which means that it is quite slow. How can I prevent the update from affecting the file and make it only affect my variable?

I know that I can achieve this through the PySpark DataFrame API, e.g.:

```
delta_table.toDF().withColumn('ma', expr('round(ma, 5)'))
```

but is there a DeltaTable-native way for me to do this?

Comment: It depends if you want the data permanently written somewhere or not. If you only want it to affect a variable and not the file, then dataframe is fine.